# How to fix error to deploy app to Heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I can’t deploy the application on heroku for an hour now, I can’t understand what the problem is.
It is not clear why it lacks modules [ '/app/db/db_func.js', '/app/app.js', '/app/bin/www' ]

folder structure:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2BGPh.png)

logs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGytI.png)

`package.json` file

```
{
  "name": "stop-schedule",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node  ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.20.0",
    "bootstrap-autocomplete": "^2.3.7",
    "bootstrap4-jade": "^1.0.0-dev",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "~4.16.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "jade-bootstrap": "^1.0.14",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysqlconnector": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "main": "app.js"
}
```

`www` file

```
var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('stop-schedule:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Also it’s not very clear what / app is, as I understand it, this is the name of the folder of my project and Heroku will automatically adjust it?

Comment: I'm not an expert at Node.js, but did you install the package mysqlconnector? `npm i mysqlconnector`

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE yes

Comment: Weird. It says "cannot find module mysql**C**onnector" with a capital C. I could get it required by using `npm i mysqlconnector` and then `const mysqlconnector = require('mysqlconnector')`

Comment: It might be a problem in your `app.js`. Can you please show that please?

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE omg, yes, my mistake. I wrote require('mysqlConnector'); with capital C. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was in mysqlconnector, the C was capitalized.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).